# seq with regex, error message for mysql quotes

Tags: command-line, shell, mysql, regex, sed

Is there some tool that auto quotes regex for seq?

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I always get this error `unterminated`s' command`

```
sed -i 's/INSERT INTO `tablename.*`/INSERT INTO \`othertable\`' *.sql
```

Do I have to quote these special mysql quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack a terminating slash (the second-last character):

```
's/INSERT INTO `tablename.*`/INSERT INTO \`othertable\`/'
```

This works in bash, but obviously will not work on Windows cmd:

```
echo INSERT INTO '`tablenameasdf`' | sed 's/INSERT INTO `tablename.*`/INSERT INTO \`othertable\`/'
INSERT INTO `othertable`
```